# Missing $ inserted, Missing } inserted, Missing{ inserted, Misplaced \crcr

Tags: tables

Please, help with this, I didn't know how to solve it.
Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[big,online]{dgruyter}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsgen,amsopn,amsbsy,theorem,graphicx,epsfig}
\usepackage[numbers,square,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!hbt]
\tiny
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\caption{Overshoots and undershoots of $\delta_\text{sym}, \omega_\text{syn}, P_\text{dfig}, I_\text{dr}, I_\text{qr}, I_\text{statcom}$ for all cases.\strut}

$\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
%\toprule
&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Case 1 (No PSS/No STATCOM)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Case 2 (Only PSS)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Case 3 (PSS + STATCOM)}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10}
 & 0.2 pu & 0.4 pu & 0.6 pu & 0.2 pu & 0.4 pu & 0.6 pu & 0.2 pu & 0.4 pu & 0.6 pu \\
 \midrule 
\multirow{2}{*}{$\delta_1$ (pu)} &{+1446\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{{Instable}} & \multirow{2}{*}{{Instable}} &{+1616\%} &{+2300\%} &{+5126\%} &{+1000\%} &{+1396\%} &{+3130\%} \\  
 &{-2676\%} &  &  &{-1491\%} &{-2110\%} &{-4794\%} &{-438\%} &{-1474\%} &{-2937\%} \\  
%\midrule

\multirow{2}{*}{$\delta_2$ (pu)} &{+70\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{{Instable}} & \multirow{2}{*}{{Instable}} &{+70\%} &{+63\%} &{+55.3\%} &{+31\%} &{+46\%} &{+40.26\%} \\  
 &{-117\%} &  &  &{-63\%} &{-54\%} &{-51.6\%} &{-17\%} &{-39\%} &{-31.46\%} \\  
 %\midrule
 
\multirow{2}{*}{$\delta_3$ (pu)} &{+61\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{{Instable}} & \multirow{2}{*}{{Instable}} &{+78\%} &{+68\%} &{+59.2\%} &{+29\%} &{+51\%} & {+43.6\%} \\  
&{-121\%} &  &  &{-66\%} &{-49\%} &{-41.3\%} &d{-10\%} &{-36\%} &{-27\%} \\  
 %\midrule
 
\multirow{2}{*}{$\omega_1$ (pu)} &{+0.4\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{{Instable}} & \multirow{2}{*}{{Instable}} &{+0.3\%} &{+0.3\%} &{+0.3\%} &{+0.3\%} &{+0.3\%} & {+0.3\%} \\  
 &{-0.34\%} &  &  &{-0.23\%} &{-0.21\%} &{-0.22\%} &{-0.21\%} &{-0.21\%} &{-0.21\%} \\  
 %\midrule
 
\multirow{2}{*}{$\omega_2$ (pu)} &{+0.6\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{{Instable}} & \multirow{2}{*}{{Instable}} &{+0.5\%} &{+0.5\%} &{+0.5\%} &{+0.5\%} &{+0.5\%} &{+0.5\%} \\  
 &{-0.54\%} &  &  &{-0.34\%} &{-0.37\%} &{-0.39\%} &{-0.33\%} &{-0.37\%} &{-0.41\%} \\  
 %\midrule
 
\multirow{2}{*}{$\omega_3$ (pu)} &{+0.7\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{{Instable}} & \multirow{2}{*}{{Instable}} &{+0.7\%} &{+0.7\%} &{+0.7\%} &{+0.7\%} &{+0.7\%} &{+0.7\%} \\  
 &{-0.54\%} &  &  &{-0.32\%} &{-0.3\%} &{-0.31\%} &{-0.31\%} &{-0.3\%} &{-0.34\%} \\  
 %\midrule
 
\multirow{2}{*}{$P_\text{dfig}$ (pu)} &{+22\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{{Instable}} & \multirow{2}{*}{{Instable}} &{+27.4\%} &{+12.7\%} &{+7.9\%} &{+13.5\%} &{+6.5\%} &{+4.2\%} \\  
 &{-16.4\%} &  &  &{-15.1\%} &{-5.6\%} &{-3.66\%} &{-4\%} &{-4.4\%} &{-2.75\%} \\  
 %\midrule
 
\multirow{2}{*}{$I_\text{dr}$ (pu)} &{+17\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{{Instable}} & \multirow{2}{*}{{Instable}} &{+9.7\%} &{+7.9\%} &{+5\%} &{+23\%} &{+19.8\%} &{+17\%} \\  
 & {$I_{\text{dr}_\text{min}}$} &  &  & {$I_{\text{dr}_\text{min}}$} &{$I_{\text{dr}_\text{min}}$} &{$I_{\text{dr}_\text{min}}$} & {$I_{\text{dr}_\text{min}}$} & {$I_{\text{dr}_\text{min}}$} & {$I_{\text{dr}_\text{min}}$} \\  
 %\midrule
 
\multirow{2}{*}{$I_\text{qr}$ (pu)} &{+56\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{{Instable}} & \multirow{2}{*}{{Instable}} &{+56.5\%} &{+19.3\%} &{+8.5\%} &{+60\%} &{+23\%} &{+12.46\%} \\ &{$I_{\text{qr}_\text{min}}$} &  &  & {$I_{\text{qr}_\text{min}}$} &{$I_{\text{qr}_\text{min}}$}&{$I_{\text{qr}_\text{min}}$} & {$I_{\text{qr}_\text{min}}$} & {$I_{\text{qr}_\text{min}}$} & {$I_{\text{qr}_\text{min}}$} \\  
$I_\text{statc}$ (pu) &--- &--- &--- &--- &--- &--- &{+598\%} &{+748\%} &{+717\%} \\  
\noalign 
\label{tab1:Table1}
\end{tabular}$
\end{minipage}
\end{center} %vs{-4mm}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

here are also the sytle files
https://file.fm/u/gd4cvpeez
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a  `\label` for the table, but no `\caption`. Unrelated: your preamble forgets to load `multirow` and `booktabs`.

Comment: I've loaded the multirow and booktabs. and the result is the same.

Comment: As I said, a \caption for the table is missing.

Comment: The caption is in the line 25 . \caption{Overshoots and undershoots of $\delta_\text{sym}, \omega_\text{syn}, P_\text{dfig}, I_\text{dr}, I_\text{qr}, I_\text{statcom}$ for all cases.\strut}

Comment: I didn't explain correctly: the \label has to be set right after the \caption. Another observation: you don't have to load `amsfonts` if you load `amssymb`. Similarly, `amsopn, amsbsy`don't have to be loaded when you load `amsmath`.

Comment: The same result @Bernard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134735/discussion-between-koko-lolo-and-bernard).

Comment: Unrelated but you should not be using `\delta_\text{sym}` like this. (1) it does not do what you think (which I'm assuming writing upright text) and (2) it is rather dangerous to assume that `_\text{foo}` will always work, the promoted solution is always to use `_{...}`. Here I'd just use `_{\textup{sym}}` instead. (Sadly this misuse of the `\text` command is very common)

Answer (score 2):

- Sorry, but your document example is awful. In code is easy to lost, it contain  a lot of clutter and errors ...
- Beside missing packages it has wrong inserted label (inside `tabular`), etc.
- Table will gain readable a lot with use of the `S` columns defined in the `siunitx` package

Anyway, see if the following (mostly off-topic) suggestion how to write a table, can help you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small]{caption} % added
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}  % added
\usepackage{siunitx}                       % added

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!hbt]
\caption{Overshoots and undershoots of $\delta_{\mathrm{sym}}, \omega_{\mathrm{syn}}, P_{\mathrm{dfig}}, I_{\mathrm{dr}}, I_{\mathrm{qr}}, I_{\mathrm{statcom}}$ for all cases.}
\label{tab1:Table1}

\sisetup{table-format=-4.2,
         group-minimum-digits=4,
         round-mode=places,
         round-precision = 2,
         round-integer-to-decimal}
    \small
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c S cc 
                                                *{6}{S}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\makecell{Case 1\\ (No PSS/No STATCOM)}} 
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\makecell{Case 2\\ (Only PSS)}}
            & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\makecell{Case 3\\ (PSS + STATCOM)}}       \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10}
    & {\makecell{0.2 pu\\ (\%)}} 
                & 0.4 pu    & 0.6 pu 
        & {\makecell{0.2 pu\\ (\%)}} 
                & {\makecell{0.4 pu\\ (\%)}} 
                            & {\makecell{0.6 pu\\ (\%)}}
    & {\makecell{0.2 pu\\ (\%)}} 
                & {\makecell{0.4 pu\\ (\%)}} 
                            & {\makecell{0.6 pu\\ (\%)}}   \\
 \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{$\delta_1$ (pu)} 
    & +1446     & \multirow{2}{*}{Instable}
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{Instable} 
    & +1616     & +2300     & +5126
    & +1000     & +1396     & +3130             \\
    & -2676     &           &
    & -1491     & -2110     & -4794
    &  -438     & -1474     & -2937             \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$\delta_2$ (pu)} 
    & +70       & \multirow{2}{*}{Instable}
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{Instable}
    & +70       & +63       & +55.3
    & +31       & +46       & +40.26            \\
    & -117      &           &
    & -63       & -54       & -51.6
    & -17       & -39       & -31.46            \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$\delta_3$ (pu)} 
    & +61       & \multirow{2}{*}{Instable}
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{Instable} 
    & +78       & +68       & +59.2
    & +29       & +51       & +43.6             \\
    & -121      &           &
    & -66       & -49       & -41.3
    & -10       & -36       & -27               \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$\omega_1$ (pu)} 
    & +0.4      & \multirow{2}{*}{Instable} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{Instable}
    & +0.3      & +0.3      & +0.3
    & +0.3      & +0.3      &  +0.3             \\
    & -0.34     &           &  
    & -0.23     & -0.21     & -0.22
    & -0.21     & -0.21     & -0.21             \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$\omega_2$ (pu)} 
    & +0.6      & \multirow{2}{*}{Instable}
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{Instable}
    & +0.5      & +0.5      & +0.5
    & +0.5      & +0.5      & +0.5              \\
    & -0.54     &           &  
    & -0.34     & -0.37     & -0.39
    & -0.33     & -0.37     & -0.41             \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$\omega_3$ (pu)} 
    & +0.7      & \multirow{2}{*}{Instable}
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{Instable}
    & +0.7      & +0.7      & +0.7
    & +0.7      & +0.7      & +0.7              \\
    & -0.54     &           &  
    & -0.32     & -0.3      & -0.31
    & -0.31     & -0.3      & -0.34             \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$P_\mathrm{dfig}$ (pu)} 
    & +22       & \multirow{2}{*}{Instable}
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{Instable}
    & +27.4     & +12.7     & +7.9
    & +13.5     & +6.5      & +4.2              \\
    & -16.4     &           &  
    & -15.1     & -5.6      & -3.66
    & -4        & -4.4      & -2.75             \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$I_\mathrm{dr}$ (pu)} 
    & +17       & \multirow{2}{*}{Instable} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{Instable}
    & +9.7      & +7.9      & +5
    & +23       & +19.8     & +17                   \\
%
    & {$I_{\mathrm{dr}_{\min}}$}
                &           &
    & {$I_{\mathrm{dr}_{\min}}$}
                & {$I_{\mathrm{dr}_{\min}}$}
                            & {$I_{\mathrm{dr}_{\min}}$}
    & {$I_{\mathrm{dr}_{\min}}$}
                & {$I_{\mathrm{dr}_{\min}}$}
                            & {$I_{\mathrm{dr}_{\min}}$} \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{$I_{\mathrm{gr}_{\min}}$ (pu)} 
    & +56       & \multirow{2}{*}{Instable}
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{Instable}
    & +56.5     & +19.3     & +8.5
    & +60       & +23       & +12.46                    \\
%
    & {$I_{\mathrm{gr}_{\min}}$} 
                &           &  
    & {$I_{\mathrm{gr}_{\min}}$}
                & {$I_{\text{qr}_\mathrm{min}}$}
                            & {$I_{\text{qr}_\mathrm{min}}$} 
    & {$I_{\mathrm{gr}_{\min}}$}
                & {$I_{\text{qr}_\mathrm{min}}$}
                            & {$I_{\text{qr}_\mathrm{min}}$}    \\
$ I_{\mathrm{statc}}$ (pu) 
    &   {---}   &   ---     &   --- 
    &   {---}   &   {---}   &   {---} 
    & +598      & +748      & +717          \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
The first version of MWE is now extended to complete table:

[image]

(redlines indicate text borders)

Comment: Do you mind changin all the `_\text{...}` they are all wrong and should not be promoted.

Comment: Solved by removing \noalign at line 67

Comment: @daleif, well `_\text{...}` is not quite correct markup, correct is `_{\mathrm{...}}`. As excuse, at cleaning OP code I forgot on this (important) detail. Corrected now.

Comment: @kokololo, what is solved, where you find `noalign` in my code?

Comment: @Zarko, thanks for your attempt, but the \noaling is in my code line 67.

Comment: @Zarko the `P_\text` part is quite wrong. Nobody is guaranteeing that `_\text` will always continue to work. And since `\text` is context sensitive (which most normal people does not realise, it is of course also not correct)

Comment: @kokololo why do you have a `\noalign` in the first place? You do realise that `\noalign` takes an argument, of which you have given none.

Comment: @daleif yes you're right, i didn't notice that becaue it's a copied part from another table.

Comment: @daleif, I'm very, very aware what you say in comment. Yes, regardless this, I was use `\text` very, very wrong. I ask everyone to accept my apology. Anyway, see edited answer. Now table is complete.